# create window service and call wcf service

Tags: wcf, push-notification

In my Application we used Android for native application and wcf service for maintain backend . Requirement is to send notification to tablet periodically. I think to use window service and call wcf service.And on my server only .Net framework is there. But i don't know how to create windows service and call wcf service.

My requirement is to call wcf service on the base of date which stored in database. Example if 30/04/2013 is stored than wcf service will call automatically on 30/04/2013

Comment: Take a look at this walkthrough on MSDN - [How to: Host a WCF Service in a Managed Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx)

Comment: If you want to simply create a windows service that calls an existing WCF service, you can do that as well.  You'll simply have the Windows Service act as a client for the WCF service.

Answer (score 0):

There are many tutorial about to consume a "WCF" web service on an android device. Here's one that I find well documented.

### Comsuming WCF Services With Android

[WCF and Android Part I](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/358867/WCF-and-Android-Part-I)

[WCF and Android: Part II](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/361107/WCF-and-Android-Part-II)

[Comsuming WCF Services With Android](http://fszlin.dymetis.com/post/2010/05/10/Comsuming-WCF-Services-With-Android.aspx)

I hope this help you

Comment: thanks for reply. But my requirement is to call wcf service on the base of date which stored in database. Example if 30/04/2013 is stored than wcf service will call automatically on 30/04/2013.

Comment: ok. In this case, you can close this issue and stand a new question! This includes a new question with a different answer

Comment: @MehdiBugnard - Actually, there's no reason to close the question, as it was never about how to call WCF services from Android platforms - it was about how to call a WCF service from a Windows Service. :)  The service is going to push notifications to the Android platform.

Comment: @DilipRam - I don't have time to give a detailed response right now, but at a high level you'd simply create the service and have it act as a client.  Search for Windows Service tutorials.  Another thing to consider is that if the Windows Service is only going to call the WCF service once a day or some other fairly infrequent time interval, it would be better to do the client as a console app and schedule it - rather than having a Windows Service that only does something once a day.